# Xamarin - Center an image or label in android screen

Tags: android, xamarin

Using Xamarin for Android, how do I display an image or label in the center of the screen as if it was another layer over top of the rest of the screen?

I want to display a loading image or text when the webview is working.  I have the code ready to show/hide a control in the front end, but I just need help to display the control overtop of the div.

Comment: do you want somthing like this? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15401073/android-proper-positioning-of-layouts/15401244#15401244